# Hangfire, .Net Core and Entity Framework: concurrency exception

Tags: c#, concurrency, .net-core, entity-framework-core, hangfire

I am developing a .Net core application with Hangfire and facing the below exception

> A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

I have used Hangfire for scheduling the jobs with 1 hour interval. I am facing the above issue when the new process/job gets started before the earlier job has finished its process.

How can we implement multiple Hangfire processes/jobs(multiple workers) to work (in parallel) to accomplish the task. (Resolved now, by using the default AspNetCoreJobActivator)

```
var scopeFactory = serviceProvider.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>();
            if (scopeFactory != null)
                GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseActivator(new AspNetCoreJobActivator(scopeFactory));
```

Now, I am getting the following exception in CreateOrderData.cs:-

> /*System.InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that
>   is likely due to a transient failure. If you are connecting to a SQL
>   Azure database consider using SqlAzureExecutionStrategy. --->
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred
>   while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. --->
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Transaction (Process ID 103) was
>   deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen
>   as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction. */

I am scheduling the hangfire cron job as below:-

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<IS2SScheduledJobs>(x => x.ProcessInputXML(), Cron.MinuteInterval(1));
```

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    string hangFireConnection = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:HangFire"];
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage(hangFireConnection);

    var config = new AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
       cfg.AddProfile(new AutoMapperProfileConfiguration());
    );

    var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
    services.AddSingleton(mapper);

    services.AddScoped<IHangFireJob, HangFireJob>();
    services.AddScoped<IScheduledJobs, ScheduledJobs>();
    services.AddScoped<BusinessLogic>();
    services.AddHangfire(opt => 
         opt.UseSqlServerStorage(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:HangFire"]));

    services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer().AddDbContext<ABCContext>(options => 
         options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:ABC"]));
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseActivator(new HangFireActivator(serviceProvider));

    //hangFireJob.Jobs();

    // add NLog to ASP.NET Core
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();
    loggerFactory.AddNLog();
    // app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");

    foreach (DatabaseTarget target in LogManager.Configuration.AllTargets.Where(t => t is DatabaseTarget))
    {
        target.ConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("Logging");
    }

    LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
}
```

Hangfire.cs

```
public class HangFireJob : IHangFireJob
{
        private ABCContext _abcContext;
        private IScheduledJobs scheduledJobs;

        public HangFireJob(ABCContext abcContext, IScheduledJobs scheduledJobs)
        {
            _abcContext = abcContext;
            this.scheduledJobs = scheduledJobs;           
        }

        public void Jobs()
        {
             RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<IScheduledJobs>(x => x.ProcessInputXML(), Cron.HourInterval(1));
        }
}
```

ScheduledJobs.cs

```
public class S2SScheduledJobs : IS2SScheduledJobs
{
    private BusinessLogic _businessLogic;

    public ScheduledJobs(BusinessLogic businessLogic)
    {
        _businessLogic = businessLogic;
    }

    public async Task<string> ProcessInputXML()
    {
        await _businessLogic.ProcessXML();
    }
}
```

BusinessLogic.cs

```
public class BusinessLogic
{
    private ABCContext _abcContext;

    public BusinessLogic(ABCContext abcContext) : base(abcContext)
    {
            _abcContext = abcContext;
    }

    public async Task ProcessXML()
    {
       var batchRepository = new BatchRepository(_abcContext);
       var unprocessedBatchRecords = await BatchRepository.GetUnprocessedBatch();

       foreach (var batchRecord in unprocessedBatchRecords)
       {
         try
         {
           int orderId = await LoadDataToOrderTable(batchRecord.BatchId);  
           await UpdateBatchProcessedStatus(batchRecord.BatchId);

           if (orderId > 0)
           {
                await CreateOrderData(orderId);
           }
         }
         catch(Exception ex)
         {
         }
       }
    }
```

CreateOrderData.cs

```
public async Task<int> CreateOrderData(int orderId)
{
  try
  {
    await OrderRepo.InsertOrder(order);
    await _abcContext.SaveChangesAsync();   
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    /*System.InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. If you are connecting to a SQL Azure database consider using SqlAzureExecutionStrategy. ---> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Transaction (Process ID 103) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction. */ 
  }
}
```

InsertOrder.cs

```
public async Task InsertOrder(Order o)
{
   // creation of large number of entites(more than 50) to be inserted in the database
    woRepo.Insert(p);
    poRepo.Insert(y);
 //and many more like above

    Insert(order);
}
```

Insert.cs

```
public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        entity.ObjectState = ObjectState.Added;
        if (entity is IXYZEntity xyzEntity)
        {
            xyzEntity.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            xyzEntity.UpdatedDate = xyzEntity.CreatedDate;
            xyzEntity.CreatedBy = _context.UserName ?? string.Empty;
            xyzEntity.UpdatedBy = _context.UserName ?? string.Empty;
        }
        else if (entity is IxyzEntityNull xyzEntityNull)
        {
            xyzEntityNull.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            xyzEntityNull.UpdatedDate = xyzEntityNull.CreatedDate;
            xyzEntityNull.CreatedBy = _context.UserName;
            xyzEntityNull.UpdatedBy = _context.UserName;
        }
        _dbSet.Add(entity);
        _context.SyncObjectState(entity);
    }
```

LoadDataToOrder.cs

```
public async Task<int> LoadDataToOrder(int batchId)
{
        //  using (var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(_abcContext))
        //  {
        var orderRepo = new OrderRepository(_abcContext);
        Entities.Order order = new Entities.Order();

        order.Guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        order.BatchId = batchId;
        order.VendorId = null;

        orderRepo.Insert(order);
        //unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
        await _abcContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        return order.OrderId;
        //  
}
}
```

HangfireActivator.cs

```
public class HangFireActivator : Hangfire.JobActivator
{
        private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

        public HangFireActivator(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }

        public override object ActivateJob(Type type)
        {
            return _serviceProvider.GetService(type);
        }
}
```

Please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: How does the `HangfireActivator` class look like? It should override the `BeginScope` method to be able to use different instances for scoped registrations. Currently looks like it uses a single global scope, thus sharing non-thread-safe `ABCContext` instance.

Comment: I have edited my question to add the HangfireActivator class.

Comment: So I was right regarding the global scope. Use the built-in [`AspNetCoreJobActivator`](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/master/src/Hangfire.AspNetCore/AspNetCore/AspNetCoreJobActivator.cs) instead that's available out of the box, i.e. remove the `HangfireActivator` class and remove the call to the `UseActivator` method.

Comment: As you said, I have commented the below code:- //GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseActivator(new HangFireActivator(serviceProvider));  But, now the ProcessInputXML() is not getting called.

Comment: services.AddHangfire(opt => opt.UseSqlServerStorage(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:HangFire"])); Is this correct?

Comment: How to use this built-in AspNetCoreJobActivator?

Comment: Ok, I found a way to use the built-in AspNetCoreJobActivator:-       
var scopeFactory = serviceProvider.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>();
   if (scopeFactory != null)
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseActivator(new AspNetCoreJobActivator(scopeFactory));

Comment: I am getting the following exception for method await CreateOrderData(orderId); ---- System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Transaction (Process ID 87) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

Comment: I have tried setting the Isolation as below but no luck. SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following solutions worked for the 2 problems:

1. Implementation of multiple Hangfire processes/jobs(multiple workers) to work (in parallel).
   Answer: This got resolved when I used the built-in `AspNetCoreJobActivator` instead that's available out of the box, i.e. removed the HangfireActivator class and removed the call to the UseActivator method.

   ```
   var scopeFactory = serviceProvider.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>();
   if (scopeFactory != null)
       GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseActivator(new AspNetCoreJobActivator(scopeFactory));
   ```
2. `SqlAzureExecutionStrategy` Exception in `CreateOrder.cs` (transaction was deadlocked)

Answer: Resolved this issue by retrying the query automatically when deadlock occurs.

Thanks odinserj for the suggestions.

Comment: Do you really need to manually assign the `AspNetCoreJobActivator`? I thought that was done automatically within `services.AddHangfire()`?